# deeplink not workin showing this error an error occurred while trying to get the sha-256 fingerprint of the keystore file

Tags: android, firebase

[image]

an error occurred while trying to get the sha-256 fingerprint of the keystore file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the debug.keystore

You can define it in gradle.

```
android {
    // ...
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('../../../.android/debug.keystore')
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }

//...
```